# Django Multiple Result Sets

Tags: python, mysql, django, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that i'm calling with cursor.execute in my Django app. The stored procedure returns 2 result sets but I can't seem to access the second one via Django. What is the proper way of accessing multiple result sets?

Comment: I haven't tested this personally, but from the specs it looks like you want the `cursor.nextset()` method: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#nextset

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper cool. that looks like it'll do it. Thanks. I'll play with it and post an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
cursor = connections['prod'].cursor()
cursor.execute('''Your SQL''')
row = cursor.fetchone()

# do what you need to do with the first result set

cursor.nextset() #sets cursor to the next result set

# fetchone or fetchall and do whatever you want with the next result set
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the second resultset from the stored procedure:

```
resultset2 = cursor.nextset().. #this returns 1 if it has result set 2 else -1..based on this call you can go for fetch
resultset2 = cursor.fetchall()
```